# TOAD for oracle connection error

Tags: database, oracle, connection, toad

I'm trying to use Toad(64bit) 12.1.0.2 and I installed oracle client 64bit.
I could not manage to connect db and "Connection Using " bar is red. Is it about oracle client or something else. Thanks^^

```
OraClient12Home1 (12.1.0.2) ORACLE_HOME:
    C:\app\client\ferhat.kuran\product\12.1.0\client_64
    ORACLE_HOME_NAME:OraClient12Home1
    ORACLE_HOME_KEY:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient12Home1

ORACLE_SID:
    NLS_LANG:AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252

SQLPATH:
    C:\app\client\ferhat.kuran\product\12.1.0\client_64\dbs

LOCAL:
    Client DLL:
        C:\app\client\ferhat.kuran\product\12.1.0\client_64\bin\oci.dll
    TNSNames.ora:
        C:\app\client\ferhat.kuran\product\12.1.0\client_64\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora
    SQLNet.ora:
        C:\app\client\ferhat.kuran\product\12.1.0\client_64\Network\Admin\sqlnet.ora
    LDAP.ora:
    Login.sql:
    GLogin.sql:
        C:\app\client\ferhat.kuran\product\12.1.0\client_64\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql
    In system PATH:
        No
    Home is valid:
        No
```

Comment: adam adam adamın dibi :))

Answer (score 0):

Add this folder to your PATH environment variable and restart Toad. C:\app\client\ferhat.kuran\product\12.1.0\client_64\bin

Comment: I solved it 3 days ago by using your way , thanks anyway.